# ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR nginx-proxy

Tags: nginx, ssl, docker, ubuntu-18.04

I've been experimenting with Docker and nginx-proxy so I can host two web apps (gophish and unms) on the same machine using ssl. When I get things set up and I try to access the sites I get the ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR in my browser. I look in my certs folder and it looks like they are being [generated correctly as this article says they should be](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nginx-reverse-proxy-docker), and it looks like it's adding the SSL info into the nginx-proxy default.conf file. Can you all give some suggestions as where to look for the issue?

```
sudo docker run -d --name site-b -e 'LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=test@minnesota-title.com' -e 'LETSENCRYPT_HOST=phish.minnesota-title.com' -e 'VIRTUAL_PORT=3333' -e 'VIRTUAL_HOST=phish.minnesota-title.com' matteoggl/gophish

sudo docker run -d --name site-a -e 'LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=dpicray@minnesota-title.com' -e 'LETSENCRYPT_HOST=unms.minnesota-title.com' -e 'VIRTUAL_HOST=unms.minnesota-title.com' httpd
```

Those are the two commands I used to create my app containers. I subbed the actual unms app out for httpd so that I'm not introducing other variables and once I have this working I should be able to fiddle and get unms working.

This is my nginx-proxy containers default.conf file

```
    # phish.minnesota-title.com
upstream phish.minnesota-title.com {
                                ## Can be connected with "bridge" network
                        # site-b
                        server 172.17.0.6:3333;
}
server {
        server_name phish.minnesota-title.com;
        listen 80 ;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
        server_name phish.minnesota-title.com;
        listen 443 ssl http2 ;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
        ssl_session_tickets off;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/phish.minnesota-title.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/phish.minnesota-title.com.key;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/certs/phish.minnesota-title.com.dhparam.pem;
        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/phish.minnesota-title.com.chain.pem;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always;
        include /etc/nginx/vhost.d/default;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://phish.minnesota-title.com;
        }
}
# unms.minnesota-title.com
upstream unms.minnesota-title.com {
                                ## Can be connected with "bridge" network
                        # site-a
                        server 172.17.0.5:80;
}
server {
        server_name unms.minnesota-title.com;
        listen 80 ;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
        server_name unms.minnesota-title.com;
        listen 443 ssl http2 ;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
        ssl_session_tickets off;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/unms.minnesota-title.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/unms.minnesota-title.com.key;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/certs/unms.minnesota-title.com.dhparam.pem;
        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/unms.minnesota-title.com.chain.pem;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always;
        include /etc/nginx/vhost.d/default;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://unms.minnesota-title.com;
        }
}
```

Any assistance you folks can provide would be a godsend! If you need to see something I haven't posted just let me know and I can grab it!